# Ranking in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, statistics

I am just curious to know if there is any way to check the user ranking in Stack Overflow.
Who has the highest points, statistics and demographics sort of stuff.

Comment: [Yes](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow), but you need to have at least 200 rep to be included in the list.

Comment: There’s also the [Users](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) page, where you can see [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) at #1, as always.

Comment: Adding to what Oded already provided I'd like to mention https://data.stackexchange.com/ where you can generate queries on your own and find out all sorts of stuff. I am also pretty sure there are a lot of queries available related to user ranking

Comment: @icktoofay: Jon isn't *always* first, once he came in second place. [Second to, uh, Jon Skeet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99502/jon-skeet-now-2-in-reputation-leagues), oddly enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are the [reputation leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow) (for every site, not just Stack Overflow).

There are some numbers on https://stackexchange.com/sites (visits, traffic and such).

But no demographics as such, though you can check out [http://quantcast.com](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com?qcLocale=en_GB) - which have some breakdowns.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting stuff.